# Intershop and Mac support

Tags: macos, intershop

time usually changes and by having some years delay also the mac gets popular for developer in europe.

Because we all love working native I am very sad about the missing intershop support for Mac.

There is also Linux and windows support so the effort/benefit ratio is probably quiet good. Does anyone know how we can push this topic to Intershop?!

I already investigated some time to use docker for mac. The x11 protocol makes streaming the UI to mac os possible. But because of a file synchronisation issue at docker for mac this is no solution. It is just to slow.

I appreciate any insights and discussions to push this topic.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Macs are getting popular for developers. Intershop is aware of that and we already successfully migrated all necessary parts of Intershop ICM. This inludes some native libraries as well as the webadapter and necessary tools.  Nevertheless we did not yet perform sophisticated tests we are confident that Mac OS X might soon become a platform for Intershop ICM for development purposes only.

Comment: any news yet? I am still on fire for native mac support :)

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no macOS support and there will most likely never be for multiple reasons:

- the market share of macOS on desktop as well as servers is just too small
- there is no Oracle DB available for macOS (however you can use SQL Server now as well with Intershop)
- there is no requirements from clients to support macOS

Being an Intershop developer using a Mac myself I run all the Intershop stuff (incl. the Studio) inside CentOS VMs (one per project) using Parallels. Works like a charm.